# Не передается текст из ckeditor

Tags: ajax, php, ckeditor, form

В общем хотел вставить ckeditor в простенькую форму отправки поста на ajax, но все время при проверке ошибка, как будто текст из ckeditor не передается :(

Сам хтмл с формой:

```
    <script src='/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>

    <form method='POST' id='post' action='/sendPosts.php'>
            <ul>
                <li><label for='title'>Заголовок:</label><input id='title' name='title' value='' type='text'></li>
                <li><label for='text'>Текст:</label><textarea id='text' name='text' value='' rows='4'></textarea></li>
                <li><input value='Опубликовать' type='submit' id='s_post'></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    <script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'text' );</script>
```

Функция ajax:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#s_post").click(function(){
            var title = $("#title").val();
            var text = $("#text").val();                
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/sendPosts.php",
                data: {"title": title, "text": text},
                cache: false,                       
                success: function(response){ ... }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

И проверка php:

```
if(!empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['text'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (title, text) VALUES ( '$title', '$text')");
        if($result == true){
            echo 0; //Ваш пост успешно опубликован
        }else{
            echo 1; //Пост не опубликован. Ошибка базы данных
        }
    }else{
        echo 2; //Заголовок и текст не могут быть пустыми.
    }
```

Подскажите может что-то не так делаю? Может надо как-то по особенному передавать текст из редактора?

Comment: Важно не забывать использовать [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/ru/mysql_real_escape_string).

Кроме того, знатоки могут вообще посоветовать прекратить использовать расширение mysql, по меньшей мере, в пользу mysqli, а лучше — PDO.

Comment: Я знаю спасибо, просто тут упростил код. И про PDO тоже)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

как делал я: создал функцию обновления объекта ckeditor

```
function CKupdate() {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

И повесил на кнопку:
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick="CKupdate();"/>

Answer (score 3):

Классическая проблема. Перед получением данных из формы необходимо выполнить updateElement()

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```